# No database found to handle jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Tags: java, maven, mysql-connector, flyway

I'm having issues executing the `mvn flyway:migrate` command. I keep getting issues that seem to be related to locating my database.

```xml
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>9.22.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddeliverydb</url>
                        <user>root</user>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-maven-plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.33</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
                <version>8.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

by using flyway plugin I wanted to migrate a the SQL script onto my Database. But I keep getting the same error every time I try to fix something.

```
"
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  0.623 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-05T18:17:11+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:9.22.3:migrate (default-cli) on project FoodDelivery: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddeliverydb -> [Help 1]
"
```

Mysql

[image: mysql]

Project Struct

[image: Project Struct]

Comment: I'd guess that (1) MySQL isn't running locally on that port, or (2) the running instance does not have a database named fooddeliverydb set up yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `pom.xml` it looks like you're missing a dependency on `flyway-mysql`. There's a *Java Usage* section in the [documentation for using MySQL](https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/supported-databases/mysql) which should cover what you need to include